# How to hide only some selected labels in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have 20 labels and 20 textboxes in my userform. If i select one option from the drop down menu of combobox then 3 labels and 3 textboxes should be locked and If i select another option from the combobox then another 3 labels and 3 textboxes should be locked and so on

I need to show in my userform that when one option is selected from the combobox some textboxes are locked (I accept that we can find that by clicking on the userform and the textbox doesn't accept any inputs) just by looking at the userform. Labels get automatically blurred when they are locked but not textboxes

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use `.BackColor = 14737632` to grey out the disabled text boxes.

It will probably be most efficient to call a separate procedure to toggle textbox properties, such as:

```
Private Const bgEnabled As Long = -2147483643
Private Const bgDisabled As Long = 14737632

Private Sub enableTB(tb As MSForms.TextBox, blEnable As Boolean)
    If (blEnable) Then
        With tb
            .Enabled = True
            .BackColor = bgEnabled
        End With
    Else
        With tb
            .Enabled = False
            .Text = ""
            .BackColor = bgDisabled
        End With
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub dd_Change()
' Example code for calling separate procedure to toggle textbox properties based on combobox value
    Select Case (dd.ListIndex)
    Case 0
        enableTB tb1, True
        enableTB tb2, False
    Case 1
        enableTB tb1, False
        enableTB tb2, True
    End Select
End Sub
```